# how does SCListener work?

Tags: iphone

How would I go about using Stephen Celis' fantastic SCListener singleton?

(http://stephencelis.com/2009/03/02/now-i-just-need-an-audience.html)

I would like to start with something incredibly simple.. like display the input volume in a textview or just display a UIImage when the listener detects something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
blowTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: 1 
                target: self 
                selector: @selctor(checkBlow) 
                userInfo: nil
                repeats: YES];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: blowTimer
                forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[[SCListener sharedListener] listen];
```

This code will basically fire up the listener, and call the checkBlow method every second.

The code for checkBlow will look something like this:

```
- (void) checkBlow
{
    if ([SCListener sharedListener] != nil)
    {
        Float32 volume = [[SCListener sharedListener] peakPower];

        if (volume > BlowingTriggerThreshold)
    {
        //DO SOMETHING AWESOME HERE
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What don't you understand, SCListener is a very simple class.

Add the AudioToolbox framework to your project then include Stephen's sample code from his posting into your source file.

I suspect your question is actually "How do I make my app respond to the return values from SCListener?" SCListerner is not asynchonous. You need to poll it to get peakValues.

For your use, I suggest you set up a timer or, extend SCListener so that it generates a callback when a peak value is reached.

Comment: thanks for replying, roger!

at this point I have a simple animation that I would like to play when SCListener detects something. Basically..

theMouse = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
theMouse.startAnimating;

Comment: Thanks, Roger. If anyone could help me with some example code, I would be greatly indebted!

Answer (score 1):

SCListener is now obsolete. It predates the AVAudioRecorder which is now part of the SDK. Look at this tutorial for audio levels:

http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/